# Spring boot JPA dao gives java.lang.NullPointerException for fetching the result

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am newbie on spring boot, I am developing application in spring boot+JPA. I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException. I have validated user first in application and if user is validated successfullly I want to fetch the menus by userId.
I am not able to figure whether the problem in daoImpl file or in service. Here is my code-

LoginController.java

```
 package com.msoft.crm.controllers;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    import com.msoft.crm.services.IUserService;
    import com.msoft.crm.entities.Login;
    import com.msoft.crm.services.LoginService;
    import com.msoft.crm.services.LoginServiceImpl;

    @Controller
    public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String showLoginPage(Model model){

        Login login = new Login();
        model.addAttribute("command", login);

        return "login1";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/validateLogin")
    ModelAndView validateLogin(@RequestParam(required = true) String username,
            @RequestParam(required = true) String password, ModelAndView modelAndView, HttpServletRequest request) {

        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = userService.validateLogin(username, password);

        modelAndView.getModel().put("message", hashMap.get("message"));
        modelAndView.setViewName((String) hashMap.get("page"));
        if(hashMap.get("page").equals("index")) {
            modelAndView.getModel().put("menuByRoleList", hashMap.get("menuByRoleList"));
            modelAndView.getModel().put("sectionSet", hashMap.get("sectionSet"));
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if(session != null) {
                session.invalidate();
            }
            session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("userId", hashMap.get("userId"));
        }
        System.out.println("controller out of first if ");
        return modelAndView;
    }
    }
```

IUserService.java

```
package com.msoft.crm.services;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.msoft.crm.entities.Users;

public interface IUserService {

    public List<Users> getAllUsers();

    public HashMap<String, Object> validateLogin(String username, String password);

    public List<Users> getMenusByRole(long userId);

    public int createUser(Users users,String logedInUserId);

    public List<Users> getUserDetails(); 

    public int editUser(Users users);

    public List<Users> checkUserNameAvail(String username);

    public int sendEmailToNewUser();
}
```

UserService.java

```
package com.msoft.crm.services;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.msoft.crm.daos.UserDao;
import com.msoft.crm.entities.Users;

@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService {
@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;
@Override
public List<Users> getAllUsers() {
    return userDao.getAllUsers();
}

@Override
public HashMap<String, Object> validateLogin(String username, String password) {
    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        List<Users> userList = userDao.validateLogin(username, password);


        if(userList.isEmpty()) {
            hashMap.put("page", "login");
            hashMap.put("message", "Username and password don't match.");
        } else {

            for (Users users : userList) {

                if (users.getActiveInd().equals("0")) {
                    System.out.println("active ind if(service):"+users.getActiveInd());
                    hashMap.put("page", "login");
                    hashMap.put("message", "Your account is inactive. Please contact admin.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("active ind(service):"+users.getActiveInd());
                    List<Users> menuByRoleList = userDao.getMenusByRole(users.getUserId());
                    Set<Users> set = new LinkedHashSet<Users>();
                    for (Users menu : menuByRoleList) {
                        Users sectionUser = new Users();
                        sectionUser.setSectionIcon(menu.getSectionIcon());
                        sectionUser.setSectionId(menu.getSectionId());
                        sectionUser.setSectionName(menu.getSectionName());
                        sectionUser.setSectionPosition(menu.getSectionPosition());
                        set.add(sectionUser);
                    }
                    hashMap.put("menuByRoleList", menuByRoleList);
                    hashMap.put("sectionSet", set);
                    hashMap.put("page", "index");
                    hashMap.put("message", "Welcome, " + users.getUsername());
                    hashMap.put("userId", users.getUserId());
                }
            } 
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return hashMap;
}

@Override
public List<Users> getMenusByRole(long userId) {
    return userDao.getMenusByRole(userId);
}
}
```

UserDao.java

```
  package com.msoft.crm.daos;

import com.msoft.crm.entities.*;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserDao {

    public List<Users> getAllUsers();

    public List<Users> validateLogin(String username, String password);

    public List<Users> getMenusByRole(long l);

    public int createUser(Users users,String logedInUserId);

    public List<Users> getUserDetails();

    public  int editUser(Users users);

    public List<Users> checkUserNameAvail(String username);

    public int sendEmailToNewUser();
}
```

UserDaoImpl.java

```
    package com.msoft.crm.daos;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

//import javax.mail.MessagingException;
//import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;





import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
//import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
//import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSInput;

import com.msoft.crm.entities.Users;


@Repository("UserDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {



    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;


//  @Autowired
//  private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public String original,recipientAddress,firstName,userName;
    @Override
    public List<Users> getAllUsers() {  
        return new ArrayList<Users>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> validateLogin(String username, String password) {

        String hql = "from Users u where u.username = :p_username and u.userPassword = :p_password";

        Query q = entityManager.createQuery(hql);
        q.setParameter("p_username", username);
        q.setParameter("p_password", password);

        List<Users> users = q.getResultList(); 

        System.out.println("users : " + users);

        return users;

    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> getMenusByRole(long userId) {


        System.out.println("In get menus role user id : " + userId);

        String hql = "select ur.role_id ,ur.role_name ,ur.speciality ,ms.section_id ,ms.section_name ,ms.section_position ,ms.section_icon ,"
                + "mi.menu_id ,mi.menu_name ,mi.menu_action ,mi.menu_position ,mi.parent_menu_id from MenuPrivileges mp ,"
                + "UserRoles ur ,MenuItems mi ,MenuSections ms "
                + "inner join ur.role_id "
                + "inner join mi.menu_id "
                + "inner join ms.section_id "
                + "where mi.active_ind  = '1' and mp.visible_ind = '1' and "
                + "mp.role_id = (select roleId from Users where userId = 3) order by ms.section_position asc";

        Query q = entityManager.createQuery(hql);
        q.setParameter("user_id", userId);

        List<Users> l = q.getResultList();
        System.out.println("l : " + l);
        return l;   
    }
    }
```

Following is stack trace-

```
 Hibernate: 


 select
        users0_.user_id as user_id1_5_,
        users0_.aadhar_no as aadhar_n2_5_,
        users0_.active_ind as active_i3_5_,
        users0_.created_by_user_id as created_4_5_,
        users0_.created_date_time as created_5_5_,
        users0_.email as email6_5_,
        users0_.fname as fname7_5_,
        users0_.lname as lname8_5_,
        users0_.login_status as login_st9_5_,
        users0_.mname as mname10_5_,
        users0_.mobile as mobile11_5_,
        users0_.photo as photo12_5_,
        users0_.role_id as role_id13_5_,
        users0_.password as passwor14_5_,
        users0_.username as usernam15_5_ 
    from
        crm_users users0_ 
    where
        users0_.username=? 
        and users0_.password=?
active ind(service):1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3912)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3698)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:716)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:572)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy75.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.msoft.crm.daos.UserDaoImpl.getMenusByRole(UserDaoImpl.java:93)
    at com.msoft.crm.daos.UserDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$da03a52e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.msoft.crm.daos.UserDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$995da1f4.getMenusByRole(<generated>)
    at com.msoft.crm.services.UserService.validateLogin(UserService.java:44)
    at com.msoft.crm.controllers.LoginController.validateLogin(LoginController.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2017-10-31 16:03:15.250 ERROR 4224 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.msoft.crm.controllers.LoginController.validateLogin(LoginController.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: I suggest you to use Spring Data JPA, btw please share your stacktrace so that people can help

Comment: Yes I added stacktrace in question.

Comment: Have you added `@ManyToMany` annotation in your Entity class?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in hql in `getMenusByRole` method, your have wrong syntax there, I suggest you to use simple sql for such complicated queries.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I use sql query or can convert sql query to HQL?

Comment: Now I can only tell that your problem is in this query, I don't know your database structure and it's also not clear for me what exactly method `getMenusByRole` should return. From declaration it should return list of users, but from name it should return list of menus. You should revise your logic first.